# Modules organization for deploying in Python

Tags: python, module

I am currently working on a Flask application. I would like to organize my .py files in different folders. This is a three that can describe all the folders.

```
Application 
    |_Interpreter
        |_
          __init__.py
          parser.py
    |_ Classes
      |_ Interfaces
          __init__.py
          Expressions.py
      |_ Operations
          __init__.py
          Arithmetic.py
          Operations.py
      |_ SymbolTable
          __init__.py
          Symbol.py
          Symbol_table.py

       __init__.py
       Driver.py
```

From my knowledge, the `__init__.py` makes the folder a module, then you should be able to import them from another files.
For example, from the file Operations.py I want to import Expressions.py. This is how I would do it:
`from Classes.Interfaces.Expression import Expression` The issue is that I keep getting a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Classes'` I've tried to use

```
import sys
sys.path.append('\..')
```

But it doesn't work all the times, in the example given it doesn't work.
I know that I can append the path of the file in my computer, but I think that it will produce some issues if I want to deploy an application to a server. Which is the best option to import modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding an `__init__.py` to you *Application* folder?

You might want to use `from Application.Classes.Interfaces.Expression import Expression` then.

Comment: Yes, sir. It has an ```__init__.py``` in there.

Comment: What happens if you use `from Application.Classes.Interfaces.Expression import Expression`?

Comment: Wow, that worked. I used ```import sys``` and ```sys.path.append('../')```. Can you explain why?

Comment: If it worked, you can mark it as answered ;) Your project structure indicates that the Application folder is part of your module hierarchy. You can read about it in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages